# Understanding large difference in cache hits

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a Leetcode hard-tagged dynamic programming [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/profitable-schemes/description/). My solution is 16x slower than a solution I found in the discussion section, and I'd like to better understand why.

Historically the recurrence relation I've used in similar problems is to advance the item index by `1` and either keep or skip the item. That's what the fast solution does. I thought that looping through items would be similar (I'm pretty sure I've seen that approach used with success elsewhere), and since I have less practice with that technique, I thought I would apply it to this problem. That's what I did in my much slower solution, and I think that's the source of the slowness. Are these two approaches not practically equivalent?

Here is the fast code that I didn't write. It takes about half a second.

```py
from typing import List
from functools import cache

class Solution:
    def profitableSchemes(self, n: int, minProfit: int, group: List[int], profit: List[int]) -> int:

        @cache
        def dfs(i, members, cur_profit):

            if i >= len(profit):
                if cur_profit >= minProfit and members <= n:
                    return 1
                else:
                    return 0

            ans = 0
            ans += dfs(i + 1, members, cur_profit)

            if members + group[i] <= n:
                ans += dfs(i + 1, members + group[i], min(cur_profit + profit[i], minProfit))

            return ans

        answer = dfs(0, 0, 0) % (10 ** 9 + 7)
        print(dfs.cacehe_info())

        return answer


solution = Solution()
answer = solution.profitableSchemes(
    100, 100,
    [2,5,36,2,5,5,14,1,12,1,14,15,1,1,27,13,6,59,6,1,7,1,2,7,6,1,6,1,3,1,2,11,3,39,21,20,1,27,26,22,11,17,3,2,4,5,6,18,4,14,1,1,1,3,12,9,7,3,16,5,1,19,4,8,6,3,2,7,3,5,12,6,15,2,11,12,12,21,5,1,13,2,29,38,10,17,1,14,1,62,7,1,14,6,4,16,6,4,32,48],
    [21,4,9,12,5,8,8,5,14,18,43,24,3,0,20,9,0,24,4,0,0,7,3,13,6,5,19,6,3,14,9,5,5,6,4,7,20,2,13,0,1,19,4,0,11,9,6,15,15,7,1,25,17,4,4,3,43,46,82,15,12,4,1,8,24,3,15,3,6,3,0,8,10,8,10,1,21,13,10,28,11,27,17,1,13,10,11,4,36,26,4,2,2,2,10,0,11,5,22,6]
)
```

Here is my slow code. It takes about 8.5 seconds.

```py
from typing import List
from functools import cache


class Solution:
    def profitableSchemes(self, n: int, minProfit: int, group: List[int], profit: List[int]) -> int:
        self.modulus = 10 ** 9 + 7
        self.groups = group
        self.profit = profit
        self.min_profit = minProfit
        self.n = n
        answer = self.solve(-1, n, 0) % self.modulus
        if minProfit == 0:
            answer += 1
        return answer

    @cache
    def solve(self, previous_crime_index, remaining_members, accumulated_profit):
        if remaining_members <= 0 or previous_crime_index == self.n - 1:
            return 0
        answer = 0
        for crime_index in range(previous_crime_index+1, len(self.groups)):
            capped_profit = min(accumulated_profit + self.profit[crime_index], self.min_profit)
            answer += self.solve(
                crime_index, remaining_members - self.groups[crime_index],
                capped_profit
            )
            answer = answer % self.modulus
            if self.profit[crime_index] + accumulated_profit >= self.min_profit and remaining_members - self.groups[crime_index] >= 0:
                answer += 1
        return answer % self.modulus


solution = Solution()
answer = solution.profitableSchemes(
    100, 100,
    [2,5,36,2,5,5,14,1,12,1,14,15,1,1,27,13,6,59,6,1,7,1,2,7,6,1,6,1,3,1,2,11,3,39,21,20,1,27,26,22,11,17,3,2,4,5,6,18,4,14,1,1,1,3,12,9,7,3,16,5,1,19,4,8,6,3,2,7,3,5,12,6,15,2,11,12,12,21,5,1,13,2,29,38,10,17,1,14,1,62,7,1,14,6,4,16,6,4,32,48],
    [21,4,9,12,5,8,8,5,14,18,43,24,3,0,20,9,0,24,4,0,0,7,3,13,6,5,19,6,3,14,9,5,5,6,4,7,20,2,13,0,1,19,4,0,11,9,6,15,15,7,1,25,17,4,4,3,43,46,82,15,12,4,1,8,24,3,15,3,6,3,0,8,10,8,10,1,21,13,10,28,11,27,17,1,13,10,11,4,36,26,4,2,2,2,10,0,11,5,22,6]
)

print(solution.solve.cache_info())
```

The fast method has `692860` cache hits, while mine has `24868771`. That's a 35x difference! I would have expected similar cache hits. I ran `python -m cProfile` on both functions, and got similar stats. The only reason for the difference I can think of is that the loop approach and that the `+1` item index approach are not equally efficient.

Comment: Did you try using a smaller example input, and examining the caches afterwards, in order to understand what happens? Did you try using a profile tool to trace the calls to the function? "I ran python -m cProfile on both functions, and got similar stats." Is there a particular reason you don't want to show us any of this information?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I tried smaller inputs and the cache hits seem to grow exponentially. What do you mean "trace the calls to the function"? Like a debugger? Yes, there is a reason I didn't post the cProfile information. The cProfile results are 50+ lines each. People are less likely to provide help on long answers, and this answer is already very long as it is.

Comment: I also think it's the different technique that's responsible for most of it. But you also have plenty of unnecessary distracting implementation differences. Nested function vs method. Equivalent variables that have different names. And equivalent but different meanings, so one starts with (0, 0, 0) and the other with (-1, n, 0). Applying the `%` only at the end vs all the time. Probably none of that matters much. The solutions would be much easier to compare/analyze if you adjusted yours so that it still uses the different technique but otherwise is as equal to the other solution as possible.